# I use SendMessage but the responses seem to be blocked

Tags: c++, winapi

I have lots of test functions to do in **RunFactoryTest** function. And they are put into an array of function pointers **cbTestArray[MAXNUM]**. After each function is executed, I want to show its return value in a ListView immediately. But the result is that nothing appear in ListView  while the test running. And until all test functions were completed, all return value show together.

Here is what I did:

```
typedef bool (*CbFactoryTestFunction)();

void RunFactoryTest(){
    CbFactoryTestFunction cbTestArray[MAXNUM] = {test1,test2,test3...};  //here are the functions used for testing
    bool ret = false;
    LVITEM lvi;  //used to set item in ListView
    for(i = 0;i < MAXNUM;i++)
    {
        ret = cbTestArray[i]();    // test success, show "OK"; fail , show "NG"
            //omit some steps
        
        if(ret){
            lvi.pszText = "OK";
        }else{
            lvi.pszText = "NG";
        }
        SendMessage(hwndListView, LVM_SETITEM, 0, reinterpret_cast<LPARAM>(&lvi));
    }
}
```

The program runs smoothly and the results are correct. But I want to be able to see the result after each test item is completed, rather than waiting until all test items are completed.

I also tried creating a thread to send messages, but it didn't work. Maybe I didn't use it correctly. How can I achieve the effect I want? Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: How are you invoking `RunFactoryTest`? Is it called in response to a window message (_e.g._ button click)? It's possible your message pump is blocked, meaning any invalidated controls are not redrawn until you process pending messages.

Comment: @paddy Yes, `RunFactoryTest` is called in response to a window message. And thanks for your advice, I find that adding `UpdateWindow(hwndListView);` after SendMessage to ListView can redrawn it immediately. Is it a correct way?

Comment: It's not ideal, but probably good enough. If you want a long-running task to not freeze your main thread, then you either need to pump/dispatch messages somewhere within that task, or (more correctly) spawn a thread for the task and post messages back to the queue for your application window via `PostMessage`. For example, you might post a custom message notifying that test 'X' had result 'Y'. Your window function would then update the list view item accordingly using `SendMessage` as you're currently doing.

Comment: A [virtual list-view control](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/use-virtual-list-view-controls) is an ideal match for a list-view whose data changes through events other than a UI event.

Comment: @IInspectable simply switching to a virtual ListView wouldn't fix the immediate problem of the loop blocking UI updates. The code would have to be redesigned to take advantage of a virtual ListView effectively.

Comment: @RemyLebeau Of course not. It allows you to decouple the data from the control responsible for the visual representation. This also means that `RunFactoryTest()` no longer has to do user-interface-y stuff (like populating a list-view control).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Spawning a thread for the long-running task **RunFactoryTest** is an ideal solution and would not block UI updates.

Use **CreateThread** to call **RunFactoryTest** instead of invoking it directly.

```
HANDLE hThread;
hThread = CreateThread(NULL,0,ThreadFunction,NULL,0,NULL);
```

In ThreadFunction, call **RunFactoryTest**.

```
DWORD WINAPI ThreadFunction(LPVOID lpParam) {       
    RunFactoryTest();
    return 0;
}
```